# Clean Chrome profile

Tags: google-chrome

Is there an easy way to run a clean chrome profile with no bookmarks, history, plugins, extensions, etc that is *not* in private mode? I need it to make screenshots of an app and I don't want my personal stuff getting in there.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new user from `Settings` ~> `Personal Stuff`.

[image: Chrome - Settings - Personal Stuff]

It'll fire a new parallel browser session independent of current one. Its just like fresh new install of Chrome in which you can do anything independently.

If multiple user option isn't available there, update to latest version (My build is 18.0.1025.140 beta-m & it was available in 17.x too).

Answer (score 2):

I've created a script that does this called [New Chrome Session](https://bitbucket.org/bradisbell/new-chrome-session/overview).

The new session has brand new history and everything.  It is essentially equivalent to what @Ali suggests... just in a convenient package.

You can either run the script directly or [download the installer](https://bitbucket.org/bradisbell/new-chrome-session/downloads/NewChromeSession_Setup.exe) which creates shortcuts for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Start out by closing all Chrome windows.
Go to this folder: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\

Your current user is the Default folder. Rename it "Backup".
Open Chrome - now you have a *new* Chrome with no configurations (not sure though if the plugins gets disabled). Chrome creates a new "Default" folder with no configuration settings.

When you're done with the screnshooting, simply delete the new Default folder (that Chrome created automatically) and rename the old Backup folder to Default.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get the [PortableApps.com version of Chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable). It's basically an install-free copy. The two options above would work just as well, though, so it's a matter of which you'd rather do.